# Edge browser cookie store location and access

Tags: winapi, cookies, windows-10, microsoft-edge

How can I programmatically enumerate and delete Edge browser's cookies?

They don't appear to be among the IE cookies in temporary internet files, and therefore seem not to be returned by the `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry`/`FindNextUrlCacheEntry` API calls.

I can see cookie files in

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\#!001\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\#!002\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\Cookies
```

What is the distinction of the three directories? How can they be accessed and individual cookies be deleted programatically?

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/21/announcing-the-latest-improvements-for-the-f12-developer-tools-in-windows-10/ Have you try this?

Comment: @Shijin: What exactly? I know the F12 developer tools allow to change cookies, but do they offer an APi to access them programmatically from a windows 32 application?

Answer (score 6):

This isn't going to be a perfect answer, but perfect enemy of good etc.

It seems like Edge still uses at least the first two locations. I don't see any recent cookies in the last one. However, maybe that is just coincidence.

I've tried running several windows and tabs to see if different folders get used by different content processes, but I've not been able to figure out much in that department, either.

What I *can* tell you is the format of these files: they are `"*\n"` separated cookie collections. Every cookie has a number of fields, which are `"\n"`-separated.

Edit (2015/12/16): Just stumbled across my own answer here again, and I need to note that some of the cookie field values themselves can end with `"*"` in which case searching for the `"*\n"` delimiter will think that the cookie finishes early. No, the values are not escaped (which would make sense...). So your best bet is really to just count the number of lines, which is unfortunate. This was fixed in the first portion of [this patch for Firefox](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/ba28fd929617), which is present in Firefox 44 and later.

The cookie fields are documented in [Firefox's source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/68c0b7d6f16ce5bb023e08050102b5f2fe4aacd8/browser/components/migration/MSMigrationUtils.jsm#573-593):

The cookie file format is a newline-separated-values with a "*" used as delimeter between multiple records.
Each cookie has the following fields:

1. name
2. value
3. host/path
4. flags
5. List item
6. Expiration time most significant integer
7. Expiration time least significant integer
8. Creation time most significant integer
9. Creation time least significant integer

At least, this seems to have been the format in IE, and the format here seems to be so similar that I would be surprised if they were materially different.

I just submitted a patch for using Firefox's existing IE cookie reading code for Edge's cookies, and that seemed to work. Here's the [reviewboard review for it](https://reviewboard.mozilla.org/r/16507/diff/1#index_header), and the [revlink in hg](http://reviewboard-hg.mozilla.org/gecko/rev/0b364656395f).

Comment: Definitely helpful, thanks. This will allow me to read and interpret the cookies. I'm still missing a way to delete a cookie so that it takes effect without restarting EDGE: When deleting one of the named files, EDGE is still sending the cookie content on subsequent requests to the website.